# crash:webview of app load a request, in a moment app crash.(website has many images, and each image size larger than 1M)

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, crash-reports

1.This method call `webview` load page.

```
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NativeCall.call_back[%@]('%@')",_pickerIndex,dateStr]];
```

2. Crash occur while stay page for a moment.
3. Crash report segment:

[image: crash report screenshot]